# Javascript: compare dates as numbers

Tags: javascript, date

It is very simple, uot I don't know the reason why the if statement is never tue:

```
var sFrom = $('#from').val(); //2013-10-04
var sTo = $('#to').val(); //2013-10-06

var dFrom = Date.parse(sFrom); 
var dTo = Date.parse(sTo); 

var dFullDate = new Date(item.created*1000);
var sDate = dFullDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (dFullDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dFullDate.getDate();
var dDate = Date.parse(sDate); //2013-10-5 should work, but nothing works

if((dDate > dFrom) && (dDate < dTo)){
  insertItem(i, item);
}
```

**UPDATE**

it is comparing two dates where one of them has a one digit day or month (in case less than 10). So all I did is added a function that transforms it to a two digit and the comparison now works.

```
function parseDateToYYYYMMDD(date){
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var day = date.getDate();

    if(month < 10){
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    if(day < 10){
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    var sDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    var dDate = Date.parse(sDate);
    return dDate;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using JavaScripts native implementation, you should try moment.js instead and rocking a better description for your problems are always a good idea

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful problem description. Say what result you expect, what result you see instead, and why that surprises you.

Comment: the if statement is never true. While it should be true (with the dates I mentioned)

Comment: What is `item.created`? Btw, do you expect any difference between `dFullDate` and `dDate`?

Comment: @Bergi: I assumed the goal there was to remove the time portion, but it was a guess. :-)

Comment: 1) item.created is jQuery time field (timestamp).
2) I am not expecting it, but it is different.
3) I think is not working because 2013-10-5 doesn't have zero in the day field. does that make sense? Because when I add it it works!

Comment: I confirm; one digit day and month fields compared with the the two digit fields was causing the issue. Unfortunately the jQuery response gives me back this one digit format and I have to work it out with a function that adds "0" when the it is one digit day or month.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browser you're using, `Date.parse` may not support that `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which was only added to the specification as of ECMAScript5 (about four years ago).

Although it was never in the spec, just about all browsers support `YYYY/MM/DD`.

So for instance, although [your code](http://jsbin.com/IxaYoXe/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/IxaYoXe/1/edit)) works on Chrome, it doesn't work on IE8. If we [update it to use `/` instead of `-`](http://jsbin.com/IxaYoXe/2) ([source](http://jsbin.com/IxaYoXe/2/edit)), it works on both Chrome and IE8.

Alternately, of course, you could always parse it yourself:

```
function parseYYYYMMDD(str) {
    var parts = str.split('-');
    return +new Date(
        parseInt(parts[0], 10),     // Year
        parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // Month (starts with 0)
        parseInt(parts[2], 10)      // Day
    ); 
}
```

If you're doing a *lot* of date work, it may be worth checking out a date library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). Probably overkill to add it just for this, though.